# Securing REST endpoints with CXF in OSGI Karaf

Tags: spring, security, rest, osgi, cxf

What is the standard approach in securing REST endpoints implemented with CXF in OSGI?

The system in question is a web application deployed as a WAB in Karaf. The application contains JavaScript making AJAX calls to REST service implemented in a separate OSGI bundle using CXF. The main Web application is secured using Spring Security (with the standard DelegatingFilterProxy). The application should be open to be used with any security provider compatible with Spring Security.

We need to be able to obtain the user information in REST services based on the principal with which the user authenticated in the main Web application.

What is the best way to secure the REST endpoints in the application?

Thank you,

Michael